# Can someone explain the difference between Expression Attribute Names and Expression Attribute Values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with DynamoDB and have consulted Amazon's documentation, which is great. But for this particular instance I can't understand the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation on this subject is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html). You can have placeholders for both names and values. For example if an item in your table has the following format:

```
{
  attribute1: value1,
  attribute2: value2
}
```

`attribute1` is an attribute name

`value1` is an attribute value

If you want to lookup something by a dynamic attribute name, or if you are using an attribute name that conflicts with a DynamoDB reserved word, then you use `ExpressionAttributeNames`.

If you want to lookup something by a dynamic attribute value, which is what you will be doing in most of your queries, you will use `ExpressionAttributeValues`.